# Validate object and assign it to something in one line

Tags: php, validation, variables

I am looking for an optimized way to do something like this:

- Check if what am I receiving from a function:

  - Is set
  - Is an array

If so, I would like to directly assign it to a variable.

For that propose, I would do something like:

- Let's suppose that I'm calling a function that returns me an array (or not).

  ```
  <?php
   $data_table = isset(Api::get($url)) && is_array(Api::get($url)) ? (array)Api::get($url) : array();
  ?>
  ```

However, doing something like this would require three calls to the function:

- The first, to check in an if statement if it is really returning something
- The second to check if the return is an array
- The thing to assign the return to $data_table variable

I've thought about doing the following, but I'm not sure how it could work like this:

```
 <?php
 $data_table = isset($result = Api::get($url)) && is_array($result) ? (array)$result : array();
 ?>
```

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a big fan of using concise code, but this is silly. Just assign it first and then do your check. Is two lines of code really that bad?

Comment: Not that bad, but I was just looking if it was even possible to do something like that :)

Comment: You are experiencing convoluted calling code because you are not returning a consistent, single datatype from your method calls. Allowing mixed datatype returns causes unnecessary logic checks making the calling code more complex. I'd suggest ALWAYS returning an array from your specified method, then you can do away with the is_array check.

Comment: What do you mean by allowing the return of mixed types? If I'm checking if it is an array, I don't really understand what do you mean.

Comment: @IvoPereira he means in your class `API` and function `get`, **always** return an array in this case and never anything else. If you need an edge case where you return `foobar`, then you `return array('foobar');` and deal with that on the other end. It's always best to have consistent results from a function.

Comment: The calling code should be aware of the method it is calling, and the expected return type. If your method always returns an array, then you can confidently treat the local results (calling code) of the method call as an array, without having to check if it is an array. Take a look at this read on the topic of "design by contract", http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract#Description

Comment: Yeah, I got it, thanks @scrowler and Mike Purcell. However I always make sure that happens, but I really do that verifications every time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `empty()`. [From the manual:](https://www.php.net/empty)

> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.

It doesn't quite check for whether it's an array, rather whether the variable (of many types) is empty, but it's a shorter way than what you're doing. I think if you want to check for an array and for isset, that's what you'll have to do - no way around it.

```
<?php
$data_table = !empty($result) ? $result : array();
?>
```

Comment: That seems to do it. So you would recommend assigning the function result to a variable then using empty() on it?

Comment: Ha, that depends on your error reporting level. At work, if I say `$foo = $bar;` and `$bar` is **not** set, I'll get errors. That's presumably why you're doing this check in the first place...

Comment: Yeah, of course. I always do this kind of checks, however I am asking you if you would assign the result of API request at first at variable, instead of the way I did in the example in the first topic (check everything in one line).